# Node ,Data centre and cluster in real life example

Tags: cassandra

Can you please elaborate Node, Data center and cluster using example of servers located in 2 different countries

Answer (score 1):

[DataStax's architecture guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/dse-arch/datastax_enterprise/dbArch/archIntro.html#Keystructures) defines these terms as following:

- **Node** - Where you store your data. It is the basic database infrastructure component.
- **Cluster** - A group of distributed nodes for storing data. A cluster can have a single node, single datacenter, or multiple datacenters.
- **Datacenter** - A group of related nodes configured together within a cluster for replication purposes. A datacenter can be a physical datacenter or virtual datacenter. Using separate datacenters prevents transactions from being impacted by other workloads and lowers latency. Depending on the replication factor, data can be written to multiple datacenters. Datacenters must never span physical locations.

In your case, you may have single cluster consisting of the 2 data centers (for every country) that contain nodes located in specific country.

Comment: where do we need multiple data centers? cant single data center hold any no. of nodes?

Comment: Usually datacenter is created from nodes in the same physical data center - this is better for fault tolerance, and controlling replication of the data. For example, if you create a data center from nodes from multiple physical DCs - if it's goes down, part of your DC will be not available, potentially with data. I recommend to take DS201 course on http://academy.datastax.com - to get understanding of building blocks

Comment: Or you can create a "logical" DC, to isolate a workload - for example, one DC to process data by Spark, and another DC to answer transactions - this is needed because Spark puts bigger load to machines, and can harm transactional load